# How to remove a tick mark in chart

Tags: qt, qt5

I use QChart and QValueAxis. How can I remove the horizontal tick mark in the red frame?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know these drawing option is controlled by the margins property. You can try the following to set this to zero:

```
yourChartAxis->setMargins(QMargins(0,0,0,0));
```

This call should control the margins of your used axis.

Comment: Cannot find the setMargins in QValueAxis.